# what is the sdk version for camera activity?

Tags: java, android

If I use the `targetSdkVersion`, my camera works fine. If I change the `targetSdkVersion` to `17`, my application stopps. I am also using an android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich phone.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

if i use android target version=17,my application has stopped

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: API level 17 = Jelly Bean.

Comment: which  sdk version,i want to use to run the camera application?

Comment: if i use target sdk version 10 means,its working,if i will use target sdk version is 17 means,after clicking the camera button,my application has stopped

Comment: post code from your button, post stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

for using the [`camera.open()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29) method (for example) you need minSdkVersion `1`.

In the top right corner of [the link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29) you'll find the API-Levels.

Comment: what is min,max,target  version.i am using ice cream sandwich phone

Comment: min = minimum API level the device has to provide for running your app, target is the API level your app is compiled at. read: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: ya,in my application,if i put android target version as 10,my applicaton is working fine,if i put the version as 17,my application has stopped after clicking the camera button

Comment: sorry,what is stack trace,i think it means logcat?is it correct

Comment: was this with API lvl 17 while triggering the button? There was no exception thrown. set logcat level to E(rror) and try again.

Comment: ya,i told previously,if i changed into target version as 17 my camera application has stopped,whether if i use target version as 10,it will works,what it might be the reason

Comment: dude, what does it help to read a logcat of a error-free application?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UtSieVfq            my log cat error,why its not working android version 17,if its not working means,it will work only upto 2.3 version phones